# Error building flask-twisted even after installing MS Visual C++ Build Studio 14.0 in Conda

Tags: python, visual-studio, conda

Using conda, I ran 'pip install flask-twisted'. It then reported that it could not build as it needed MS Visual C++ 14.0 which can be obtained with VS C++ Build Tools. Well even after installing MS Visual Studio 2015 Build Tools, add the MS Visual Studio bin path to my environment variables and rebooting the PC, it still reports the same build error ... that it needs MS Visual Studio C++ 14.0.

Any suggestions as how to fix this build error?

Comment: which is the error exactly?

Comment: The error message is basically how I described it; it needs MS Visual Studio Build Tools. Strange thing is that in my Windows run prompt, it cannot find cl.exe or MSbuild.exe. Let me reinstall this and then I give you a more accurate error message, that is if does happen again.

Comment: is there a vcvarsall.bat in your VS Build tools?

Comment: After installing MS Visual Studio Build Tools, I was able to find msbuild.exe. Cl.exe does not get install, and I did not find vcvarsall.bat using the Windows run command prompt. Frustrating having to reinstall it a second time. I was able to successfully finish the build.  Thanks for helping out.